# Copy workbook containing macro to a workbook without macro

Tags: vba, excel

I am able to duplicate a workbook (copy to a desired location) which contains a macro in the background. This duplicate copy also contains the same macro.
My Problem is I do not want this duplicate workbook to have a macro with it. Can anyone tell how to do it?

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Wich version of Excel are you using?

Comment: I don't know, but maybe this page will help: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Save your workbook as macro-free, i.e. simply as Excel Workbook. For my Excel 2007 this is done using:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ThisWorkbook.CheckCompatibility = False
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="D:\DOCUMENTS\Book1.xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Correct path & name as you wish.

Read more about `SaveAs` method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185%28v=office.14%29.aspx
...and available File Formats: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198017%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Hope that was helpful)

Comment: +1. I've seen a suggestion that you use the FileFormat numbers rather than the enumerations, for forward-compatibility.

Comment: @DougGlancy agree entirely, but for immediate solution this was generated using macro-recorder and `Application.DisplayAlerts` + `CheckCompatibility` pieces added) Moreover, for the beginner "xlOpenXMLWorkbook" is more understandable than number.