# How save an Excel file copy without macro and copy the original file then?

Tags: excel, vba

I do the following -

```
Sub SaveCopy()
    Set xls = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    'xls.DisplayAlerts = False
    'Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Dim CurrentFile As String
    CurrentFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName
    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Replace(ThisWorkbook.FullName, "xlsm", "xls"), FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Settings").Delete
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
    Application.Workbooks.Open Filename:=CurrentFile

    xls.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

This code has the following problems:

1. When I open the result file, it says that the file format is not equal to the file content
2. It doesn't open the original book again (`Application.Workbooks.Open` line is not executed)

How can I fix it?

Comment: `xlOpenXMLWorkbook` should save as `xlsx` not `xls`. And if you `ActiveWorkbook.Close` then the code is immediately stopped because you close the workbook this code is running at.

Comment: see **"Copy workbook containing macro to a workbook without macro"** 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14583914/copy-workbook-containing-macro-to-a-workbook-without-macro

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy workbook containing macro to a workbook without macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14583914/copy-workbook-containing-macro-to-a-workbook-without-macro)

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, thanks. What should I do to be able to open the file? Is there any way to open it before `Close` is called, by to close correct book after that?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
Sub SaveCopy()
    Dim CurrentFile As String
    CurrentFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName

    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Replace(ThisWorkbook.FullName, "xlsm", "xlsx"), FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Settings").Delete

    Application.Workbooks.Open Filename:=CurrentFile 're-open original file

    ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True 
    'The line above will terminate this macro immediately
    'Everything beyond this line will not execute.
End Sub
```

Note that if the workbook `CurrentFile` has a `Workbook_Open` event, that this will also immediately be terminated when `ThisWorkbook.Close` runs.

---

A more save alternative is to use the [Workbook.SaveCopyAs method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.savecopyas).

- Advantage is, that this method keeps the original workbook open and just saves a copy.
- Disadvantage is that `.SaveCopyAs` cannot change the file type, because it does not support the parameter `FileFormat:=`.

That means you must save a copy in the same file format first, then open that copy and save it again with `.SaveAs` to change the file format and then delete the temporary copy.

```
Sub SaveCopyAdvanced()
    Dim CurrentFile As String
    CurrentFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName

    Dim CopyFileName As String
    CopyFileName = Replace(ThisWorkbook.FullName, ".xlsm", "_COPY.xlsm")

    'save a temporary copy but keep the original workbook unchanged and open 
    ThisWorkbook.ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=CopyFileName 

    Dim CopiedWb As Workbook
    Set CopiedWb = Application.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=CopyFileName)
    CopiedWb.Sheets("Settings").Delete

    'convert filename to xlsx
    CopiedWb.SaveAs Filename:=Replace(ThisWorkbook.FullName, "xlsm", "xlsx"), FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook

    'close it (we already saved it)
    CopiedWb.Close SaveChanges:=False

    'kill temporary file with _COPY
    Kill CopyFileName
End Sub
```

Comment: @PEH I think in your first program two lines regarding setting `CopiedWb` and parenthesis`(` may be like this `Set CopiedWb = ThisWorkbook`     then in next line ` CopiedWb.SaveAs Filename:=Replace(ThisWorkbook.FullName, "xlsm", "xlsx"), FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook` without opening and closing`()` before Replace. I am not too sure but please check it up.

Comment: Does `SaveAs` return workbook? This line of code returns `Expected Function of Variable` error. And if I remove parenthesis, as @skkakkar recommends, then `Syntax Error`.

Comment: @LA_ Mehhh, you are both right. Of course `.SaveAs` does **not** return a workbook my bad :( I fixed it. Thanks for the follow up.